# Enterprise-grade template printing system

Tags: web-services, printing, templates, jms, enterprise

I'm looking for an enterprise-grade template printing system. I'm interested in every software I can get my hands on to evaluate. Commercial or not.

What I need - a separate system ready to receive tags in order to print (digital or paper) a template (like a contract, invoice, etc). Templates should be managed by the same software. It should operate via web services or via enterprise bus (preferable JMS or MQSeries connectors).

Can I ask for some names and possibly some URLs? Anything will be helpful even if it does not fit the requirements exactly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but for the Googlers out there, we use a couple of products to render documents in XSL-FO (a W3C standard paper specification that we generate using XSL) either to PDF, PostScript, etc.  We use it to show documents online as well as bulk print a few hundred thousand of them monthly.

- RenderX (.NET, Java, whatever)
  provides a very powerful solution for
  our bulk printing needs
- IBEX PDF Creator (.NET
  only) for online rendering to PDF

Answer (score 0):

Calligo is a commercial package from InSystems.  Can't reach the web site right now; could be a bad sign.

Then there are [these](http://java-source.net/open-source/content-managment-systems) open source possibilities.

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid Insystems webpage still does not work. The list doesn't provide any information on a "print server" functionality. And I'm not really interested in a CMS system. I primarily need a software which will print or return a filled out template given a list of tags with information.